# Ubuntu 15.10 Cinnamon DE menu not functioning properly

Tags: 15.10, menu, environment

Welcome fellow Ubuntu enthusiasts.  I have a rather simple yet equally irritating problem with both of my laptops running Ubuntu 15.10  with Cinnamon 2.6.13 desktop environment.  On most menu items EXCEPT Accessories, I get a right click of 3 options Add to Panel Desktop or Favorites.
The Accessories Menu item only right click toggles with a _ below the program item.  It does this for all items in Accessories on BOTH laptops.  One is a HP Probook with 8 gb ram and the other is a Dell Latitude D505 with 2 gb ram.  Everything else seems to work as intended.  I have searched the forums, tried uninstalling and reinstalling Cinnamon and so far haven't found a reason for this seemingly unusual occurrence.   Anyone have any ideas on how to remedy?

Answer (score 0):

...the solution became evident to me after research and trial and error.  When having Ubuntu 15.10 with Cinnamon desktop environment installed and then adding both a top and bottom panel to the desktop, ONLY 1 panel can have customized panel size. if both top and bottom panels are re-sized, then above problem is experienced.  Top or bottom is ok BUT not both.